# Entity db first: how to name two different relationships between two tables with different names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with .NET MVC 4 and entity framework and I am using db first approach. Since I use db first I don't want to change anything in the model manually.

I have two tables. For example "FirstTable" and "SecondTable". There are two relationships between those two tables named differently in the db but when I generate the Entity model, for a record from FirstTable I get record.SecondTable and record.SecondTable1.

Is there any way to have different names instead of this versions with/without 1?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of relationship does your two tables share ? does that make it M:N relationship between your tables. If it does, then your code might not be work in all conditions due to multiplicity constraints. I believe that due to multiple constraints between two tables is making the framework confused and it might be changing the name of the table.

Comment: Two 1:N relationships where record from SecondTable can have many records from FirstTable.